# Simple way to send strings and files via TCPIP

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient, system.net

I want to make a simple client-server application. The server waits for connection from clients. The client can send various queries (short strings of less than 100 char) to the server and the server should respond to these queries by sending strings or files. 
I found code online that uses a tcpListener.AcceptSocket() and I can send and receive strings from server and code that uses tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient() and I can send files to a different server program.
Below there is a function for sending files via TcpIP and one for sending strings via TcpIP. How should the server code look like, to acommodate both functions? The server is a console program.

```
    public void SendFileViaTCP(string sFile, string sIPAddress, int portNo)
    {
        byte[] sendingBuffer = null;
        TcpClient client = null;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "";
        lbConnect.Items.Clear();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        Application.DoEvents();
        NetworkStream networkStream = null;
        int bufferSize = 5000;
        string checksum = CalculateMD5(sFile);
        lbConnect.Items.Add("File " + sFile + " checksum = " + checksum);
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(sIPAddress, portNo);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected to the Server...\n";
            networkStream = client.GetStream();
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long fsLength = fileStream.Length;
            int nPackets = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(fsLength) / Convert.ToDouble(bufferSize)));
            progressBar1.Maximum = nPackets;
            Application.DoEvents();

            int currentPacketLength;
            for (int i = 0; i < nPackets; i++) {
                if (fsLength > bufferSize) {
                    currentPacketLength = bufferSize;
                    fsLength -= currentPacketLength;
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                else {
                    currentPacketLength = Convert.ToInt32(fsLength);
                }

                sendingBuffer = new byte[currentPacketLength];
                fileStream.Read(sendingBuffer, 0, currentPacketLength);
                networkStream.Write(sendingBuffer, 0, (int)sendingBuffer.Length);

                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Sent " + fileStream.Length.ToString() + " bytes to the server";
            fileStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally {
            networkStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    void SendString(string str, string sIPAddress, int portNo)      
    {
        try {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            lbConnect.Items.Add("Connecting...");
            Application.DoEvents();

            // use the ipaddress as in the server program
            var tsk = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(sIPAddress, portNo);
            tsk.Wait(3000);  // here we set how long we want to wait before deciding the server is not responding.            

            lbConnect.Items.Add("Connected");
            lbConnect.Items.Add("Sending string: " + str);
            Application.DoEvents();

            Stream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();

            byte[] ba=asen.GetBytes(str);
            lbConnect.Items.Add("Transmitting...");
            Application.DoEvents();

            stream.Write(ba,0,ba.Length);

            byte[] bb=new byte[100];
            int k = stream.Read(bb,0,100);

            string sResponse = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                sResponse += Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
            }

            lbConnect.Items.Add(sResponse);
            Application.DoEvents();

            tcpClient.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            lbConnect.Items.Add("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, add tcplistener which listens on all incoming connection attempts.

Comment: The listener will get an availablesocket event callback when the client connects.

Comment: I have TcpListener in the server code, but how can the server differentiate if what is coming is a string command or a file?

Comment: I would recommend to write a separate Connect-method on the client instead of opening new connections for Evert new message.

Comment: Ok. I would recommend to use two message types, eg "A" is always the first char in string messages and "B" is always the first char in file messages. E.g "AThisIsAString".

Comment: Thanks. I can do that. I will wait and see if there are better ideas.

Comment: Never forget to the the actual bytes read/written return by the `fileStream.Read(` and the `networkStream.Write(`. Those method returns the bytes handled.

Comment: Your description sounds an awful lot like a homebrewed webserver. Is there a reason you've overlooked http for this?

Comment: It is not a home web server. I have very few special tasks to do and I must have all code within my application.

Comment: Thanks for advice J. van Langen. I will check the code and include what's necessary.